# Let $G$ be non-abelian of order $15$. Prove $Z(G)=1$. Use $\left< g\right>\le C_G(g),\forall g\in G$ to show $G$ has at $\le 1$ class equation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

Assume that $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $15$. Prove $Z(G)=1$. Use the fact that $\langle g \rangle \leq C_G (g)$ for all $g\in G$ to show that there is at most one possible class equation for $G$.

$N.B.:$ Yes, I realize that for other obvious reasons, such a group $G$ cannot exist, but this is the premise of the question at any rate.
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}$

$\textit{Proof:}$
First we recall that the Class Equation for $G$ is given by the following for each representative $g_i$ of a distinct conjugacy class in $G$:
\begin{equation*}
|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{i=1}^{r} [G: C_G (g_i)]
\end{equation*}
Next, we make use of the fact that $\langle g \rangle\leq C_G (g) \leq G$ for each $g\in G$. Since $G$ is non-abelian, then for any $g\in G$ we have $C_G (g) \in \{1,3,5\}$, and since $\langle g \rangle\leq C_G (g)$ therefore assuming $g$ is nontrivial we have two cases: $|\langle g \rangle|=3$ or $|\langle g \rangle|=5$. In either case, by LaGrange's Theorem it is easy to see then that $|\langle g \rangle|=|C_G (g)|$. Therefore for any $g_i \in G$ we will have that $[G:C_G (g_i)]\in \{3,5\}$ and so we may describe the Class Equation of $G$ by the following:
\begin{equation*}
|G|=15=|Z(G)|+5a+3b
\end{equation*}
Then, by Cauchy's Theorem, since $3$ and $5$ are both primes which divide $|G|=15$, $a$ and $b$ are at least $1$. Next, since $Z(G)\leq G$ therefore $|Z(G)|\in \{1,3,5\}$ ($15$ is excluded since $G$ is non-abelian) and we will consider three cases:

[i.] $|Z(G)|=5$. Then $15=5+5a+3b$, or $10=5a+3b$, which has no solutions for $a,b\in \N$ with $a,b\geq 1$.

[ii.] $|Z(G)|=3$. Then $15=3+5a+3b$, or $12=5a+3b$, which also has no positive solutions in $\N$.

[iii.] $|Z(G)|=1$. Then $15=1+5a+3b$, which has precisely one solution of $a=1,b=3$.

Therefore $G$ has at most one Class Equation, and in particular $Z(G)=1$. $\Box$

Is this correct?

Comment: Or easier: if $\;|Z(G)|=3, 5\;$ , then $\;\left|G/Z(G)\right|=5,3\;$ so $\;G/Z(G)\;$ is cyclic , which is impossible since $\;G\;$ isn't abelian.

Comment: Of course. But in that case, I'm not even sure why you need the first part at all, where the question requires using the fact that $\langle g \rangle \leq C_G (g)$?

Comment: Clearly, this sequence of problems is trying to get you to use the class equation, as practice for using the class equation. I mean, in reality there are *no* "nonabelian groups of order 15" anyway, so there are plenty of ways of proving whatever you want to prove about one of them.

Comment: it might be late but I think your answer might be wrong because you say that $|C_G(g)| \neq |G|$ for all $g \in G$ because $G$ is non-abelian, however the diedheral group $D_8$ is non abelian and $r^2 \in Z(G)$ so $C_G(r^2) = D_8$. So in general it's not true to say that $|C_G(G)| \neq |G|$ simply because $G$ is non-abelian.

Comment: @H4z3 I did not say that statement anywhere.

Comment: then why "Since $G$ is non-abelian, then for any $g \in G$ we have $C_G(g)∈\{1,3,5\}$"?

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is nonabelian of order $pq$, then the center has order either $1$ or $p$ or $q$. The latter two are ruled out because the class equation would yield, respectively: $pq=p+kq$ and $pq=q+lp$ ($k$ and $l$ are the number of noncentral congjugacy classes, in the two situations): both contradictions, because $q\nmid p$ and $p\nmid q$. Therefore $Z(G)=1$.